# How to create UIButton for ios7 & ios6 4-inches and 3.5 screen for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on iOS7 & iOS6(3.5 inches and 4 inches screen).

- I am displaying 6 buttons in UIView.The six buttons divided in to 3 rows.like Each two buttons displaying single row.
- Total rows displayed are 3.
- I have also integrated iAD in bottom of the view.

My problem is in `iOS7 4-inches` screen it display the proper way. In iOS 6 with a 4-inch screen it is not display properly. I have issues with alignment. iOS7 with 3.5 inches is also getting some alignment issues. But iOS6 with 3.5 inches it displays fine.

I don't know how to fix the alignment issues. This is my sample code:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];

if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))

{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault];

naviBarObj=[[UINavigationBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 64)];

[self.view addSubview:naviBarObj];

[naviBarObj setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:38.0f/255.0f green:45.0f/255.0f blue:51/255.0f alpha:1.0]];

// Weekly Audio Button Creation..

weeklyAudio=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[weeklyAudio addTarget:self action:@selector(weeklyPredictions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[weeklyAudio setTitle:@"WEEKLY" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

weeklyAudio.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

weeklyAudio.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

[weeklyAudio.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];

[weeklyAudio setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 10, 10, 10)];

[weeklyAudio.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];

weeklyAudio.frame=CGRectMake(10, 100, 140, 120);

weeklyAudio.layer.cornerRadius=5;

weeklyAudio.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:232.0f/255.0f green:52.0f/255.0f blue:27.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

[self.view addSubview:weeklyAudio];

weeklyAudioImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 10, 48, 48)];

weeklyAudioImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"48*48.png"];

[weeklyAudio addSubview:weeklyAudioImage];

weeklyAudio.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

// Create Yearly Audio Button.

yearlyAudio=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[yearlyAudio addTarget:self action:@selector(yearlyPredictions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[yearlyAudio setTitle:@"YEARLY" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

yearlyAudio.titleLabel.textAlignment=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

yearlyAudio.titleLabel.numberOfLines=2;

[yearlyAudio.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

[yearlyAudio setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 10, 10, 10)];

[yearlyAudio.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];

yearlyAudio.frame=CGRectMake(160, 100, 140, 120);

yearlyAudio.layer.cornerRadius=5;

yearlyAudio.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:16.0f/255.0f green:144.0f/255.0f blue:209.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

[self.view addSubview:yearlyAudio];

yearlyAudioImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 10, 48, 48)];

yearlyAudioImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"48*48.png"];

[yearlyAudio addSubview:yearlyAudioImage];

yearlyAudio.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;


// iAD integration.

ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

adView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 580, 320, 40);

adView.delegate=self;

adView.autoresizingMask =UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

}


else

{

 weeklyAudio=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[weeklyAudio addTarget:self action:@selector(weeklyPredictions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[weeklyAudio setTitle:@"WEEKLY" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

weeklyAudio.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

weeklyAudio.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

[weeklyAudio.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];

[weeklyAudio setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 10, 10, 10)];

[weeklyAudio.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];

weeklyAudio.frame=CGRectMake(10, 50, 140, 110);

weeklyAudio.layer.cornerRadius=5;

weeklyAudio.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:232.0f/255.0f green:52.0f/255.0f blue:27.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

[self.view addSubview:weeklyAudio];

weeklyAudioImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 10, 48, 48)];

weeklyAudioImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"48*48.png"];

[weeklyAudio addSubview:weeklyAudioImage];

weeklyAudio.autoresizingMask =UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

// Create Yearly  Button Audio

yearlyAudio=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[yearlyAudio addTarget:self action:@selector(yearlyPredictions) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[yearlyAudio setTitle:@"YEARLY" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

yearlyAudio.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

yearlyAudio.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

[yearlyAudio.titleLabel setTextAlignment: NSTextAlignmentCenter];

[yearlyAudio setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 10, 10, 10)];

[yearlyAudio.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0]];

yearlyAudio.frame=CGRectMake(160, 50, 140, 110);

yearlyAudio.layer.cornerRadius=5;

yearlyAudio.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:16.0f/255.0f green:144.0f/255.0f blue:209.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];

[self.view addSubview:yearlyAudio];

yearlyAudioImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(45, 10, 48, 48)];

yearlyAudioImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"48*48.png"];

[yearlyAudio addSubview:yearlyAudioImage];

yearlyAudio.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin  | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;

ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

adView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 40);

adView.delegate=self;

[self.view addSubview:adView];

}

}
```

Comment: @pawan i am already using Autolayout.But it is not working good

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 read this. it may clear your doubts

Comment: help me any body......